# Prove that $p\le x<p+1$ by well ordering property

Tags: number-theory, analysis, well-orders

by using well ordering property prove that if $x$ is a positive real number then there exist unique integer $p\ge0$ such that $p\le x<p+1$.

Comment: Just well-ordering property is not enough. You need to use some fact like the Archimedean property as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The set of positive integers $n$ with $x<n$ is not empty.

What conclusion can be drawn from this on base of the fact that $\mathbb N$ is well- ordered?